# Why can't I import PyTube?

Tags: python, api, youtube, pytube

I would like to import PyTube but keep getting this error. How can I fix it?

Code:

```py
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube

print("Give URL:")
url = input()

pytube.YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytube.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytube
  File "/home/python/pytube.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pytube import YouTube
ImportError: cannot import name 'YouTube'
```

Comment: You named your file *pytube.py*. Rename it to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael Szczesny stated, you named the file you executed with the same name as the library. Rename your script to something else and it should work.

Python checks the imports in a particular order that can be seen in `sys.path`:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

In my case, it gives:

```
['', '/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/lib/python36.zip', '/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/lib/python3.6', '/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

telling me it first searches in the current directory `''`, then, in `'/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/lib/python36.zip'` etc. and finally in `'/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/lib/python3.6/site-packages'` where the packages' files are stored.

In your case, since the script found a `pytube` in the first directory it searched (ie `''`), it did not bother to check if there was a package with the same name in the last directory of the list. It just stopped there and tried importing your own `pytube.py` script.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytube

print ('Download video from web by python')
url = input ("Enter video url ")


pytube.YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download("/storage/emulated/0/Download/")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.